Play in UDH derailleur mount (transmission t)
I have this mounting system on my bike it's for the transmission t type to use the udh.

However when I install and tighten up to torq I'm getting side to side play in the derailleur as seen in this vid
https://youtube.com/shorts/se39xnSc6KA?si=IDDwnL9nz5AdvShq
There is no washer that comes with this so I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. How would you folks get rid of the play?

Check the width of the dropout. If I’m reading it right, it should be 12.5 +/- 0.2 mm in section. See https://www.universalderailleurhanger.com/downloads/90-7518-190-000_E9_RELEASED.pdf
